# Proportionality involving multiple variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I am having trouble with the following textbook question (translated):

Suppose we have 5 different variables: $X$, $Y$, $Z$, $U$ and $V$ such that:

- (1) $X$ is proportional to $Z$
- (2) $Y$ is inversely proportional to $V$
- (3) $U$ is inversely proportional to $X$
- (4) $Z$ is inversely proportional to $Y.$

Which of the following statements is **not** true?

- (A) $X$ is proportional to $Y$
- (B) $Y$ is inversely proportional to $U$
- (C) $V$ is inversely proportional to $Z$
- (D) $U$ is proportional to $V$
- (E) $Z$ is proportional to $U$

--

How can I efficiently solve these types of questions? For statement (A), I thought:

- As $X$ gets larger, $Z$ gets proportionally larger (1).
- As $Z$ gets larger, $Y$ gets proportionally smaller (3).
- So, as $X$ gets larger, $Y$ should get smaller - statement A should be false.

Applying the same logic to the other statements, I get that in fact that every statement above—not just one—is false.

Comment: Do you know what "proportional" and "inversely proportional" mean?  Use the definitions to write out each of the given facts algebraically. the rest should be easy.

Comment: @lulu Can you provide an example for a statement?

Comment: The first statement is $X=k_1\times Z$ where $k_1$ is some non-zero constant.

Comment: I get the same results you get, that all of the statements are false.

Answer (score 1):

> > - (1) **$X$ is proportional to $Z$**
>
> - As $X$ gets larger, $Z$ gets proportionally larger (1).

Suppose that $X=-Z$ (proportional but opposite in sign); then as $X$ increases, $Z$ *decreases*!

Also, note that statement (1) means:

**for some non-identically-zero expression $k$ that is independent of** $X$ **and** $Z,$ $$\textbf{if the variables in $k$ are held constant, then }X=kZ.$$

> > - (1) $X$ is proportional to $Z$
> > - (4) $Z$ is inversely proportional to $Y$
>
> - So, as $X$ gets larger, $Y$ should get smaller - statement A should be false.

Suppose that $X=YZ$ is the only dependency among $X,Y$ and $Z;$ then statements (1) and (4) are satisfied, yet when $Z=1,\:$ $X$ and $Y$ *increase in tandem*!

> > - (1) $X$ is proportional to $Z$
> > - (2) $Y$ is inversely proportional to $V$
> > - (3) $U$ is inversely proportional to $X$
> > - (4) $Z$ is inversely proportional to $Y$
>
> > - (A) $X$ is proportional to $Y$
> > - (B) $Y$ is inversely proportional to $U$
> > - (C) $V$ is inversely proportional to $Z$
> > - (D) $U$ is proportional to $V$
> > - (E) $Z$ is proportional to $U$

The counterexample $$V=X=Z=\frac1U=\frac1Y$$ shows that the given collection of statements implies none of the five options.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it this way (using the definition of proportional and inversely proportional):

$X = aZ$ for some $a>0$ (exact value of $a$ is not known and not important)

$Y = b/V$ for some $b>0$

$U = c/X$ for some $c>0$

$Z = d/Y$ for some $d>0$

To solve the first problem, let't try to express $X$ in terms of $Y$

$X = aZ = ad/Y = k/Y$ where $k = ad > 0$. This shows that $X$ is inversely proportional to $Y$, so the first statement is false.

You can use this type of simple manipulation to solve the rest.

Your way of thinking about it qualitatively ($Z$ and $X$ increase together, instead of saying $X = aZ$) is perfectly fine for solving these problems too. Sometimes it's just easier to write out the mathematical formulae.